# Android ICS freezes live wallpaper?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I just developed my first android app - a live wallpaper. It was working perfectly on 2.3.7, but now I installed ICS 4.0.3 on my phone and it freezes badly when the screen gets locked. After that it takes a lot of time to unfreeze when I unlock the screen. Any clues would be greatly appreiated! 
Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the enormous information you gave I would say that you coded wrong. Hope that helped! *irony off*

Comment: I suggest you to use traceview to trackdown the bottleneck that is causing the freezing. More information here: http://bit.ly/5B3ijQ. 
On a complete naive|user's perspective, my Nexus S feels more laggy with ICS comparing to when Gingerbread was running on it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've tried the cube live wallpaper from the examples, it behaves in the same way. Probably a ROM problem.